# How can I quickly scroll down the output of git commands?

Tags: git, macos, version-control, iterm

I have to show my commits using `git show c36432`. The files are very big and it sometimes takes a long time to go line by line.

What can I do to move fast, like page by page? I am using `iterm` as terminal on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Press the space bar. By default, git uses the `less` pager to display long output, and the space bar moves down a page at a time in `less`.

Other `less` keyboard shortcuts also work, such as typing `/` followed by a word you want to search for, which can be handy when searching a Git diff or log.

Comment: Press (capital) G to scroll to the end.