# scrolling down git diff from mac terminal

Tags: git, macos

I am using git on terminal on OS X 10 Yosemite.

When I do git diff I get long list of changes and sometimes I just need to scroll to the end but I couldn't figure out a way to do that other than to hold the keydown on MacBook pro and then it scrolls slowly.

if I press FN+down key then it does not scroll unless I have made the scroll down journey already down using the down button, but does not go further down...

any advice will be appreciate this is very annoying... :(

Comment: How about when you press `space` or `w`?

Comment: yes it works, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I quickly scroll down the output of git commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365970/how-can-i-quickly-scroll-down-the-output-of-git-commands)

Comment: Adding `export LESS=-R` to `~/.zshrc` file works for me.

Answer (score 66):

`git diff` uses the same pager as [less](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) Unix command.

- Use keys `d` and `u` to go down / up half pages (forward / backward technically)
- Jump to last line: `G`
- `h` for help
- `!` to input a command  (eg. `git add` while scrolling)

---

Another trick is storing the diff as a patch file like they used to do in the email days! Then you can open up the patch in any program. Some examples:

```
git diff --staged > ~/patch
git show someCommitSHA > ~/patch
git diff main myBranch > ~/patch
git diff head '*pathWildcard*' > ~/patch
```

`git apply ~/patch`

Normally you would use the patch by applying the diff, but you can just open the file in any text editor. It's useful if you don't want to make a full commit out of your diff, but still want to use it somewhere else or send it to a friend

---

You can also use `git diff master | grep -C 2 someKeyword` to show diff +/- 2 lines around some keyword

Comment: No need to create a patch and then open it in sublime. Just run `git diff | subl`

Comment: The OS X terminal has some magic integration with less which breaks when less is run as a subprocess by git: when run as `git diff | less`, scrolling forward is possible with the touchpad gesture, but with the output of `git diff` it only scrolls the terminal output and cannot tell `less` to scroll forward.

Interestingly, `git help` does not suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 35):

`git config --global core.pager "less -+\$LESS -RS"`

On my new macOS laptop, that got the git log scroll working as I'd expect (page up / page down buttons working, color, wheel scroll).

Why does this work? Per the [git-config manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git-config):

> Note that git sets the LESS environment variable to FRSX if it is unset when it runs the pager.

Per the [less manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

> -X Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.

I don't actually know what any of that means, but that X breaks page up / page down / scroll wheel.

> -F Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.

If you don't have X, then F breaks when there's no paging, presumably because less exits immediately and something prevents it from printing directly to the terminal.

Comment: This needs to be upvoted more. Helped me out immensely

Comment: Is there a way to have this and retain the behavior of just printing to the terminal for small outputs? I like this when using `git diff` or `git show`, but it's very annoying when using `git branch -avv` to open up a `less` instance with 10 lines rather than just printing. It prevents me from starting to type the next command and then copying the git branch name.

Comment: Posted an answer with my solution to that at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68491919/1907543. I was going to edit this one, but looking at the edit guidelines we're only supposed to fix formatting issues, not add whole new content. So - new answer it is!

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 22.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Per mzabaluev's comment:

> The OS X terminal has some magic integration with less which breaks
>   when less is run as a subprocess by git: when run as git diff | less,
>   scrolling forward is possible with the touchpad gesture, but with the
>   output of git diff it only scrolls the terminal output and cannot tell
>   less to scroll forward. Interestingly, git help does not suffer from
>   this problem. – [mzabaluev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2217151/mzabaluev) Jan 4 at 0:39

This magic also includes enabling page up (FN+up) and pagedown (FN+down).

A quick and dirty way around this is to invoke `less` yourself with:

```
git diff --color=always | less -r
```

The command line options retain git's coloured output. I got them from [Can less retain colored output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/can-less-retain-colored-output)

Comment: The problem with this approach is we lose the coloring, which helps a lot to interpret the code changes.

Comment: Ran into this with a new laptop, looked up config on an old laptop, `git config --global core.pager "less -+\$LESS -RS"` got it working with scrolling as I'd expect. Not entirely sure why.

Comment: @LeonardoRaele my solution keeps the colouring (on my machine at any rate)

Comment: @ognockocaten you should put that in as an answer, it's the best one so far.

Answer (score 6):

```
brew install less
git config --global core.pager "less -+\$LESS -RSF"
```

Installing a newer version of less fixes the bug where `-F` causes small outputs to entirely disapear without `-X`, and then the config command removes `-X`, which is what breaks scrolling.

This will replace the `less` version MacOS ships with with the latest, but as they are the same utility (unlike GNU coreutils vs. BSD coreutils), this should not break things.

#### Explanation

This is an extension to [ognockocaten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057559/1907543).

That answer suggests:

```
git config --global core.pager "less -+\$LESS -RS"
```

This removes two options:

`-F` / `--quit-if-one-screen`:

> Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.

and `-X` / `--no-init`:

> -X Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.

This works for the question at hand, but is suboptimal, as `less` will always switch to an alternate page regardless of how small the output is. So, even for small commands like `git diff`, you'll get a full alternate screen.

Reading closely, it seems like re-adding `-F` would fix this. However, a combination of two things causes this to break:

- on the version of less MacOS ships with, `487`, less will switch to the alternate screen *first*, before checking if the text is small enough, and thus print the output to the alternate screen buffer. This was fixed in version `530` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107355/39135)
- on MacOS, without `-X`, switching back from the alternate to main buffer clears the screen and thus erases all text that was just printed to the alternate screen buffer.

So just re-adding `-F`, you'd get small outputs being completely erased, as if they were never printed. We can't re-add `-X` to fix this, as that breaks scrolling, but we *can* update to a newer version of `less`!

Thus it all comes together - we can use homebrew to install the latest stable `less` version, and then configure the pager to include the `-F` option, as per the command block at the start of this post.

Answer (score 5):

You can use any of the less commands to navigate the history. [See: frequently used less commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29#Frequently_used_commands)

Examples:
In the bottom left of your terminal, you must be seeing something like this.
[image]

In the above example, the history has 221 lines out of which the current window is showing lines 21-62.

**Go directly to a line number**:
You can directly go to a line by typing

```
line-number (followed by) g   (no spaces necessary)
```

for example: to go to line#100 just type `100g`

**Skip x-number of lines:** 
Type a number and hit enter.

**Scroll down and scroll down**
Use Fn

Or use below aternatives.

Hit space bar. as ILI suggested.

**Scroll up by a page**

Hit 'w'

**Go home**

Fn  Left-Arrow
**Go to end**
Fn Right-Arrow

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way is to use `less` to read the diff output. You need to use the `--color` and `-R` options to keep the coloration.

```sh
git diff --color | less -R
```

This works fine for me.

You could make a macro for this command.

---

Since I wrote this answer, I discovered that you can use the `LESS` environment variable to set options for `less`, so you can do the same as above even easier:

```sh
LESS=R git diff
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **iTerm2**, you can enable mouse / touchpad scrolling by doing the following:

1. Open **iTerm2**
2. In the menu bar, click **iTerm2** -> **Settings**
3. Click the **Advanced** tab
4. Set the option ***"Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode"*** to **Yes**

Answer (score 1):

Just push `h` in terminal with opened less after `git diff` - it call help window with shortcuts

[screenshot with less help text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFk5D.jpg)

Comment: Hi Dmitry, consider copy/pasting code instead of images.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on [@ognockocaten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469204#59057559), you can change the default options passed to the `less` command by changing the `LESS` environment variable.

To do that, add this line to your startup script. (probably `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, or `~/.bash_profile`)

```bash
export LESS="RS"
```

And it should work for any new terminal you open.

Answer (score 0):

fn + option (⌥) + down

worked for me on mac